# What is the optimal way to extract values between braces in bash/awk?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have the output in this format:

```
Infosome - infotwo: (29333) - data-info-ids: (33389, 94934)
```

I want to extract the last two numbers in the last pair of braces. Some times there is only a single number in the last pair of braces.

This is the code I used.

```
echo "Infosome - infotwo: (29333) - data-info-ids: (33389, 94934)" | \
  tr "," " " | tr "(" " " | tr ")" " " | awk -F: '{print $4}'
```

Is a more clean way to extract the values? or a more optimal way?

Comment: What do you mean by clean/optimal?  What is your criteria for success?

Comment: I mean a more professional way to extract the info

Comment: Changing the word from "optimal" to "professional" doesn't help. :)

Comment: I think the OP is curious if there is a cleaner "more elegant" way to do this than with four pipes!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk -F '[()]' '{print $(NF-1)}' input | tr -d ,
```

It's kind of refactoring of your command.

Comment: That's pretty awesome .. I wonder if OP wants the comma still?

Comment: @kev so you can specify character sets for the field separator in awk? I didn't know that - that's pretty handy.

Comment: @Levon You can use any regex. As far as I know, it works in `gawk`.

Comment: @kev I'll have to explore this capability some more, pretty cool. Thanks.

Comment: @kev I added another solution to my answer that builds on yours, but eliminates the need for `tr`.

Comment: @Levon - but as Kev said, it works in gawk.  And in nawk (FreeBSD), but not in the awk that comes with Solaris, and possibly not others.  Jus' sayin' ... be careful, test everything and whenever you can, write for the lowest common denominator. :)  (+1 from me too, though.  This is subtle, and perfect.)

Comment: @ghoti So noted, thanks. I think my first solution should be "universal" (though hard to say, I don't have access to all versions)

Answer (score 3):

```
 awk -F\( '{gsub("[,)]", " ", $NF); print $NF}' input
```

will give

```
 33389  94934
```

I am a bit unclear about the meaning of "optimal"/"professional" in this problem's context, but this only uses one command/tool, not sure if that qualifies.

*Or* building on @kev's approach (but not needing `tr` to eliminate the comma):

```
awk -F'[(,)]' '{print $4, $5}' input
```

outputs:

```
33389  94934
```

Comment: This is also elegant.  And portable (at least, the first one)!  :)  +1

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done in pure bash.  Assuming the text always looks like the sample in the question, the following should work:

```
$ text="Infosome - infotwo: (29333) - data-info-ids: (33389, 94934)"
$ result="${text/*(}"
$ echo ${result//[,)]}
33389 94934
```

This uses shell "parameter expansion" (which you can search for in bash's man page) to strip the string in much the same way you did using `tr`.  Strictly speaking, the quotes in the second line are not necessary, but they help with StackOverflow syntax highlighting.  :-)

You could alternately make this a little more flexible by looking for the actual *field* you're interested in.  If you're using GNU awk, you can specify RS with multiple characters:

```
$ gawk -vRS=" - " -vFS=": *" '
  { f[$1]=$2; }
  END {
    print f["data-info-ids"];
    # Or you could strip the non-numeric characters to get just numbers. 
    #print gensub(/[^0-9 ]/,"","g",f["data-info-ids"]);
  }' <<<"$text"
```

I prefer this way, because it actually interprets the input data for what it is -- structured text representing some sort of array.